# How to add all *.py files to the package with setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a directory with a lot of *.py files (scripts) and subdirs with *.py files.

How to add all *.py files from root directory to the package?

Now my setup.py is

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my-awesome-helloworld-script',  # This is the name of your PyPI-package.
    version='0.1',  # Update the version number for new releases
    scripts=['????????????????????'],  # The name of your scipt, and also the command you'll be using for calling it
    # Packages
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

As you can see, I've solved addition question of folders with `find_packages()`.

But how to add *.py files from root directory?

I am packaging with command `python.exe  setup.py sdist`.

Thank you!

Comment: you can use the `glob` package for this.

Comment: I am sorry, can you provide code example for that? Thank you!

Comment: This is considered bad design, unless you provide a single module package. What's the intent behind this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

pckgs=find_packages()
pckgs.append('.')

setup(
    name='my-awesome-helloworld-script',  # This is the name of your PyPI-package.
    version='0.1',  # Update the version number for new releases
    # scripts=[''],  # The name of your scipt, and also the command you'll be using for calling it
    # Packages
    packages=pckgs,
)
```